# Multivariate multinomial probit

Tags: estimation, multivariate-analysis, multinomial-distribution, probit, multinomial-probit

I would like to jointly estimate 4 variables. Two of them are categorical and the two others are binary. So I thought about a "multivariate multinomial probit model", but did not find much.

- What would be the best solution in my case?
- Is there a built-in function or package I can use?
- I am working with a Stata, but can switch to R or Matlab if needed.

Comment: A link to start reading: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multinomial-probit